# Fit p5 canvas in a DOM element as background

Tags: html, reactjs, p5.js

My goal is to fit p5 canvases as background to a dynamically generated list in a React webpage. Right now, I am unable to directly affect the style of the dynamically generated p5 canvas so that it'll fit nicely as a background (z-index: -1) in my `<article>`.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4'
import P5Wrapper from 'react-p5-wrapper'
import projectList from './projectList'
import './projects.css'

const TILE_SIZE = 200

export default class Projects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      projects: (projectList || {}).projects || {}
    }
  }

  _list = () => {
    const { projects } = this.state
    const listProjects = projects.map((project) => {
      const { name, description } = project
      return (
        <article 
          key={uuidv4()}
          style={projectContainer}
        >
          <header style={header}>
            {name}
            <p>{description}</p>
          </header>
          <P5Wrapper sketch={sketch} />
        </article>
      )
    })
    return listProjects || null
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav style={mainContainer}>
        <section style={projectListContainer}>
          {this._list()}
        </section>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}

const mainContainer = {
  flex: 1,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}

const projectListContainer = {
  flex: 1,
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
}

const projectContainer = {
  position: 'relative',
  height: TILE_SIZE,
  width: TILE_SIZE,
  marginTop: 32,
  marginLeft: 32,
  marginRight: 32,
  borderRadius: 32,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(1,1,1, 0)',
  overflow: 'hidden',
}

const header = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  alignItems: 'flex-start',
  height: TILE_SIZE,
  width: TILE_SIZE,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  padding: 16,
  color: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
  zIndex: 1,
}

function sketch (p) {
  p.setup = () => {
    let cnv = p.createCanvas(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, p.WEBGL)
  }
}
```

My assumption is that I can either style by

```
<P5Wrapper
  sketch={sketch}
  style={canvas} 
/>
```

Which doesn't work. Or I have to import a separate CSS file just for the `<canvas>` element? I would much rather be able to affect the p5 object directly within the same file.

Update: I looked at the generated DOM elements and basically `<P5Wrapper>` injects

```
<div>
  <canvas />
</div>
```

I was able to manually affect the canvas by using an external CSS import `'./projects.css'`, which is not ideal. I still want a solution that avoids external CSS for just a canvas.

```
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work neatly with styled-components. With it, I can specify only the `div` and `canvas` elements within this react component to affect.

Import:

```
import P5Wrapper from 'react-p5-wrapper'
import styled from 'styled-components'
```

Updated render:

```
<ItemContainer key={uuidv4()}>
  <header>
    {name}
    <p>{description}</p>
  </header>
  <P5Wrapper sketch={sketch} /> {/* <div><canvas></div> */}
</ItemContainer>
```

styled-components in the same file:

```
const ItemContainer = styled.article`
  position: relative;
  height: ${TILE_SIZE}px;
  width: ${TILE_SIZE}px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-right: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;

  div {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: ${TILE_SIZE}px;
    width: ${TILE_SIZE}px;
  }

  canvas {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: rgba(138,43,226,1);
  }

  header {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: ${TILE_SIZE - 32}px;
    width: ${TILE_SIZE - 32}px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 16px;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    z-index: 1;
  }
`
```

I had to remove any parent `background-color`, specifically in my `root` because of the `z-index: -1`. The behavior is different from importing a plain ol' CSS just for the `<canvas>` element.